# Entity Framework Code First not detecting new ICollection<> in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm currently working on a MVC5 web app with Entity Framework. I'm using Code First and want to update one of my models. Problem is that it's not detecting the new ICollection Bookings that I added, but it does detect the new string Name that I add.

My Model class:

```
public class Room : BaseEntity
{
    public enum Type
    {
        Rest, Fight, Game, Work, Train
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public Type RoomType { get; set; }
    public bool HasBooking { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tamagotchi> Tamagotchis { get; set; }
}
```

The new migration:

```
public partial class Update1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Room", "Name", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Room", "Name");
    }
}
```

My DataModel:

```
public class DataModel : DbContext
{
    public DataModel()
        : base("name=DataModel")
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Tamagotchi> Tamagotchis { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea: i'd be very grateful! I already tried most of the solutions on here, including wiping all Migrations, restarting Visual Studio etc.

Update: So i tried to add the same list to the Tamagotchi class and that worked. Maybe i'm trying to do something that isn't possible at all? Here are my other model classes:

```
public class Booking : BaseEntity
{
    public Booking()
    {
        Tamagotchis = new List<Tamagotchi>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tamagotchi> Tamagotchis { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

Other one:

```
public class Tamagotchi : BaseEntity
{
    public Tamagotchi()
    {
        Coins = 100;
        Health = 100;

    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //TODO: Max length 10
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Coins { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public int Boredom { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }

}
```

Update: Check DevilSuichiro's comment for the fix to this.

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not detecting*? What is *it*? Where occurs which error?

Comment: Change `ICollection<T>` to `List<T>`

Comment: @RobertStettler There is no error at any point. That's the weird thing. Package manager says it completes the migration without any issues.

Comment: @JohnyL why? ICollection should be perfectly fine

Comment: @JohnyL Changing it to List<T> did not work sadly.

Comment: were tamagotchis in the context before the migration? is there a FK already? because if there is, the adding of a navigation property of collection type should not change the schema anymore (reflected in the DbMigration)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro They were. I think this was causing the issue. I have now reworked this so it's working properly. Thank you!